# Hidden, unowned and undeletable file

Tags: windows-7, file-permissions

I have a nasty little file on my desktop that doesn't show up in the Explorer; only in the CLI. It seems that it's not owned by any account and is not deletable as seen here:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/sgGHuAm.jpg]

and this is what Cygwin shows me:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/6rUsCD6.png]

I tried

```
del /f out~1.web
takeown /f out~1.web
cacls out~1.web /T /E /C /G Cambion:F
```

from an elevated command prompt, but I always get an ACCESS DENIED error.
What else can I do?

Comment: When you ran `takeown` in particular, did you do so from a regular or from an elevated command prompt?

Comment: Elevated of course.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not reproducible (fixed by a restart) so unlikely to help others.

Answer (score 1):

First, boot in Safe Mode and run virus and malware checks.  If those are clean, try resetting the permissions to default using an administrator command line as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22453562/2877364):

```
icacls "out~1.web" /reset /c /t
```

Once the permissions are reset, you should be able to delete the file if no process has it open.

Comment: It is bad practice to link to other answers, and for that reason I will not vote up this answer. If you edit your answer and copy/paste in the part about doing this, I'll happily change my mind and vote this up.

Comment: I've upvoted the answer. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I just rebooted and the file is gone. For some obscure reason although it was already deleted it still showed up using

```
dir /x
```